# android autocomplete text from xml in non-activity class

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am trying to use android `AutoCompleteTextView`, in my case I have textview with type `AutoCompleteTextView` but it has to be used in a class which is extended from `LinearLayout`. So I cannot give reference to the xml `AutoCompleteTextView` and if I give reference (which is wrong, because there is no `setContentView()` method in that class) it gives error on adapter of `NullPointerException`. I don't know if I am able to present my problem well. This is the piece of code I am using from android developer's site.

```
public class InputAutoComplete extends LinearLayout {
..... //here is no setContentView() method
.....
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, data);
    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete); //this is AutoCompleteTextView
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

xml for AutoTextComplete

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  </AutoCompleteTextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note: I know there could be a solution of custom design but at the time I am working on that, but still if I can get some solution for this issue it will be helpful. Thank you

Comment: Any special reason for doing this in LinearLayout instead of Activity class?

Comment: Yes, am using custom design! layouts